# How to use unpivot operator to combine rows and columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, unpivot

I need to group customers by `GroupName`. `Customers` can be duplicated on each `GroupName`. Each `GroupName` has a unique number called `"GroupCode"` in table `OCQG`. Customer table (`OCRD`) has separate column for Each `GroupCode`. As an example, `C-0001 customer` can have more group names.We can identify `GroupCodes` for each customer by see `Group1,...,Group64` column values.(If this value = Y).Table structure as follows.Please help me.
I tried following query.But it didn't work.

```
SELECT p.CardCode, REPLACE(p.QryGroup,'GROUP','') groupcode, ocqg.GroupName
FROM ocrd UNPIVOT 
    ( value
     FOR groupcode IN ([QryGroup1],[QryGroup2],[QryGroup3])
     ) as p,
     ocqg
WHERE value = 'Y' and 
ocqg.GroupCode = REPLACE(p.groupcode,'GROUP','')
order by p.CardCode
```

Table Structure as follows,
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: post your table structure and expected output in text format, that is much helpful for us.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `APPLY` for this purpose:

```
SELECT ocrd.CardCode, v.groupcode, ocqg.GroupName
FROM ocrd CROSS APPLY 
    (VALUES (1, QryGroup1),
            (2, QryGroup2),
            (3, QryGroup3),
            . . .
    ) v(GroupCode, Value) JOIN
    ocqg
    ON ocqg.GroupCode = v.GroupCode
WHERE v.value = 'Y'
ORDER BY p.CardCode;
```

`UNPIVOT` is bespoke syntax for SQL Server and Oracle that does one thing.

On the other hand, `APPLY` implements "lateral join"s.'  These are very powerful -- much more powerful than `UNPIVOT` -- and supported by more databases.

Comment: Yes.This is also a good method. But this syntax is not working in HANA

Comment: @kith . . . Your question is tagged SQL Server, not Hana.  Your question tagged Hana is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60912704/how-to-convert-sql-unpivot-query-to-hana-sql.